# Do I have to enforce RECOMPILATION of stored-procedure every time to prevent 'parameter sniffing'?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I recently experienced how slow a sproc can work because of the parameter sniffing 'feature' of SQL Server.

As far as I understood, the parameter set used in the 1st call of a sproc results a compilation of the sproc and this execution plan is cached.

And *for different set of parameters passed this execution plan might not be efficient at all*.

**QUESTION:**
So, in order to prevent potential performance hit of parameter sniffing, should I enforce SQL Server to recompile each time the sproc is called?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a local variable if we are talking only a few parameters.

```
DECLARE @MyLocalVariable INT = @MySpParameter
-- now use @MyLocalVariable instead of the SP parameter
```

Otherwise you can optimize it for a specific variable with `OPTIMIZE FOR`

If none of that works for you then you would have to use `RECOMPILE` and take the hit of recompiling the stored procedure each call. That might be a small hit compared to the run time of the stored procedure depending on your use case.